# Should iptables do source NAT on invalid TCP packets?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, openvpn

I stumbled over a peculiar issue:

I have set up an OpenVPN server  on Ubuntu 16.04, on my home network, to enable my Android phone and Debian based notebook to send all internet traffic through my home network. To that end I have configured an iptables MASQUERADE rule to spoof the source IP address of my OpenVPN clients tun0 tunnel interfaces. I all works very well from an end user perspective. However, my router/firewall sometimes complain of "martian source" packets, having source IP address of the tun0 interface of my client - in this case the Android phone. I was puzzled about these messages and wondered if they could pose a security risk - not likely since martian packets are normally dropped in routers. But curiosity toook over and I investigated it further. To make a long story short, this is what I found:

1. When you turn off the phone (only the screen) it's OpenVPN client makes a soft exit, which breaks some of the TCP connections over the tun0 tunnel interface to the OpenVPN server.
2. When you turn on the phone again the OpenVPN connection is restarted automatically. When this happens the Ubuntu firewall typically detect a number of invalid packets from the phone to internet IP addresses - e.g. google.com.   These messages are TCP packets of type RST/ACK, FIN/ACK, and RST, and most of them are invalid in the sense of iptables firewall connection tracking.
3. Now to puzzling part: The iptables firewall happily route these invalid packets onwards to the Ubuntu servers outgoing Ethernet interface to the router, where they result in the martian source packet warnings, but their IP source addresses are the original android phone tun0 interface IP addresses, NOT the Ubuntu servers outgoing IP address. All non-invalid packets get the correct MAAQUERADE source NAT processing.

Above conclusions were based on use of wireshark to capture traffic, and iptables statistics of the following rule to capture invalid packets in the forward chain.

I have managed to drop these packets using the following rule:

```
-A FORWARD -s xxx.xxx.169.0/24 -o p2p1 -p tcp -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
```

After introduction of this rule there are no longer any martians in the router, and wireshark no longer see packets on the Ubuntu outgoing Ethernet interface with source address from the phone.

I should mention that during testing, the phone was not connected to the home LAN via WiFi, so all traffic is OpenVPN UDP protocol, which goes through my home router/firewall to OpenVPN server on the Ubuntu server.

I hope someone know if the described behavior is in line with the design of Linux netfilter/iptables, or is it a bug? I suspect the problem is somehow related to iptables connection tracking where the broken TCP connections have lost their connection tracking entries in iptables, which in turn somehow prevent the source NAT logic of the MASQUERAD rule to do it's thing.

I'd be happy ff someone could offer a deeper insight on this and maybe also could comment on any security aspects - can it be exploited somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is thorough and complete. Very well done. I went through the same investigation 8 years ago.

It is not a bug, even though it keeps getting reported as a bug. From my notes at the time:

The NAT engine simply can not know what to do with an INVALID packet, so it is passed without address translation. So such packets need to be identified and dropped. This requirement is incredibly NOT obvious in most documentation.

Please also see [this bug report](https://bugzilla.netfilter.org/show_bug.cgi?id=693), particularly [comment 11](https://bugzilla.netfilter.org/show_bug.cgi?id=693#c11).

I am not aware of any particular security concerns with this. I am aware that some ISPs can get upset with non-routable packets being sent. In my iptables rule set I have many rules, in addition to the INVALID checks, to ensure that packets never leave my LAN with non-routable source or destination IPs (i.e. 192.168.X.X, 10.X.X.X, 172.16.X.X, ...)

2.5 years after implementing the rule as you have:

```
-A FORWARD -s xxx.xxx.169.0/24 -o p2p1 -p tcp -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
```

There was a case of a non NAT'd packet escaping from my LAN.The cause was a poorly formed ICMP packet from a smart phone (something that should never occur, but did. It was a bogus header length). So the protocol specification was dropped:

```
-A FORWARD -s xxx.xxx.169.0/24 -o p2p1 -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link which confirm that iptables is working as expected.  I will simply keep my forward drop rule, and maybe increase the netfilter close_wait parameter from the default.  Need a little experimentation to avoid excessive resouce use for the conntrack data.

Comment: @storestyggeulv : If my answer dealt with your issue, please consider to accept or upvote it. That way future readers get some indication as to its value (or lack of).